# How can I set a static IPv6 address for a WiFi connection?

Tags: wi-fi, ipv6

I am running CyanogenMod 12 (Android L) on a OnePlus One, and would like to set a specific wireless network to use a static IPv6 address. I see a menu option for doing this for the IPv4 address (as well as hostmask/gateway) but not for v6.

Currently the connection is getting an address using SLAAC, on the prefix I am using. It gets its routing advertisement from a machine running a tunnel client and `radvd`.

Is there a method for doing this that preferably does not require root, and needs to only be run once and applies for that specific connection?

Comment: I don't believe Android itself offers this, so it's not surprising that CM doesn't.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, would you know if there is a terminal-based process, or one that involves a third-party app?

Answer (score 3):

Open a terminal in your android or connect to your smartphone from pc with "adb shell" command. Then type "ip a" command, just to know how your needed interface is called. For me it is "wlan0 ".
Now, type the following command

```
 # ip -6 addr add 2001::your:want:ed_s:tati:c_ad:dres/CIDR dev interface
```

For example,

```
# ip -6 addr add 2222::1234/64 dev wlan0
```

Now execute "ip a" again or go to settings advanced and ensure, that your wanted address was assigned.
As I can see, this method do not survive rebooting. For permanent configuration you need use another way.

Comment: I don't want a static dns server for v6, I would like to set the device's address to something static instead of using SLAAC.

Comment: That doesn't really help this question though--the answer should be applicable to the question being asked. Do you have an answer for how to set the *device* IPv6 address?

Comment: @glockstar You can add your last comment into your answer. That will be helpful both to OP as well as a future reader here.

Comment: Does that method you mention persist across reboots and wifi connection changes?

Comment: @hexafraction Being based on the interface MAC address, in most cases the SLAAC address is _static enough_. Do you have a use case where this won't work?

Comment: @Michael I had not noticed this; I was under the impression that my specific android rom included a feature for changing MAC addresses for the purposes of connecting to WiFi and for SLAAC, for privacy reasons, but I would need to recheck carefully.

Comment: @hexafraction I'm running CM12 and (1) my Wi-Fi MAC address isn't changing on its own, and (2) I've never seen an option anywhere to change it.

Comment: Ip tools no longer works since Android 13